# Access ApplicationCall in object without propagation

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor

Is there a thread-safe method in Ktor where it is possible to statically access the current ApplicationCall? I am trying to get the following simple example to work;

```
object Main {

    fun start() {
        val server = embeddedServer(Jetty, 8081) {
            intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Call) {
                // START: this will be more dynamic in the future, we don't want to pass ApplicationCall
                Addon.processRequest() 
                // END: this will be more dynamic in the future, we don't want to pass ApplicationCall

                call.respondText(output, ContentType.Text.Html, HttpStatusCode.OK)
                return@intercept finish()
            }
        }
        server.start(wait = true)
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Main.start();
}

object Addon {

    fun processRequest() {
        val call = RequestUtils.getCurrentApplicationCall()
        // processing of call.request.queryParameters
        // ...
    }
}

object RequestUtils {

    fun getCurrentApplicationCall(): ApplicationCall {
        // Here is where I am getting lost..
        return null
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to get the ApplicationCall for the current context to be available statically from the RequestUtils so that I can access information about the request anywhere. This of course needs to scale to be able to handle multiple requests at the same time.

I have done some experiments with dependency inject and ThreadLocal, but to no success.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the application call is passed to a coroutine, so it's really dangerous to try and get it "statically", because all requests are treated in a concurrent context.

Kotlin official documentation talks about [Thread-local in the context of coroutine executions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#thread-local-data). It uses the concept of CoroutineContext to restore Thread-Local values in specific/custom coroutine context.

However, if you are able to design a fully asynchronous API, you will be able to bypass thread-locals by directly creating a custom CoroutineContext, embedding the request call.

**EDIT**: I've updated my example code to test 2 flavors:

- *async* endpoint: Solution fully based on Coroutine contexts and suspend functions
- *blocking* endpoint: Uses a thread-local to store application call, as referred in [kotlin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#thread-local-data).

```
import io.ktor.server.engine.embeddedServer
import io.ktor.server.jetty.Jetty
import io.ktor.application.*
import io.ktor.http.ContentType
import io.ktor.http.HttpStatusCode
import io.ktor.response.respondText
import io.ktor.routing.get
import io.ktor.routing.routing
import kotlinx.coroutines.asContextElement
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import kotlin.coroutines.AbstractCoroutineContextElement
import kotlin.coroutines.CoroutineContext
import kotlin.coroutines.coroutineContext

/**
 * Thread local in which you'll inject application call.
 */
private val localCall : ThreadLocal<ApplicationCall> = ThreadLocal();

object Main {

    fun start() {
        val server = embeddedServer(Jetty, 8081) {
            routing {
                // Solution requiring full coroutine/ supendable execution.
                get("/async") {
                    // Ktor will launch this block of code in a coroutine, so you can create a subroutine with
                    // an overloaded context providing needed information.
                    launch(coroutineContext + ApplicationCallContext(call)) {
                        PrintQuery.processAsync()
                    }
                }

                // Solution based on Thread-Local, not requiring suspending functions
                get("/blocking") {
                    launch (coroutineContext + localCall.asContextElement(value = call)) {
                        PrintQuery.processBlocking()
                    }
                }
            }

            intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.ApplicationPhase.Call) {
                call.respondText("Hé ho", ContentType.Text.Plain, HttpStatusCode.OK)
            }
        }
        server.start(wait = true)
    }
}

fun main() {
    Main.start();
}

interface AsyncAddon {
    /**
     * Asynchronicity propagates in order to properly access coroutine execution information
     */
    suspend fun processAsync();
}

interface BlockingAddon {
    fun processBlocking();
}

object PrintQuery : AsyncAddon, BlockingAddon {
    override suspend fun processAsync() = processRequest("async", fetchCurrentCallFromCoroutineContext())

    override fun processBlocking() = processRequest("blocking", fetchCurrentCallFromThreadLocal())

    private fun processRequest(prefix : String, call : ApplicationCall?) {
        println("$prefix -> Query parameter: ${call?.parameters?.get("q") ?: "NONE"}")
    }
}

/**
 * Custom coroutine context allow to provide information about request execution.
 */
private class ApplicationCallContext(val call : ApplicationCall) : AbstractCoroutineContextElement(Key) {
    companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<ApplicationCallContext>
}

/**
 * This is your RequestUtils rewritten as a first-order function. It defines as asynchronous.
 * If not, you won't be able to access coroutineContext.
 */
suspend fun fetchCurrentCallFromCoroutineContext(): ApplicationCall? {
    // Here is where I am getting lost..
    return coroutineContext.get(ApplicationCallContext.Key)?.call
}

fun fetchCurrentCallFromThreadLocal() : ApplicationCall? {
    return localCall.get()
}
```

You can test it in your navigator:

http://localhost:8081/blocking?q=test1

http://localhost:8081/blocking?q=test2

http://localhost:8081/async?q=test3

server log output:

```
blocking -> Query parameter: test1
blocking -> Query parameter: test2
async -> Query parameter: test3
```

Answer (score 2):

The key mechanism you want to use for this is the `CoroutineContext`. This is the place that you can set key value pairs to be used in any child coroutine or suspending function call.

I will try to lay out an example.

First, let us define a `CoroutineContextElement` that will let us add an `ApplicationCall` to the `CoroutineContext`.

```
class ApplicationCallElement(var call: ApplicationCall?) : AbstractCoroutineContextElement(ApplicationCallElement) {
    companion object Key : CoroutineContext.Key<ApplicationCallElement>
}
```

Now we can define some helpers that will add the `ApplicationCall` on one of our routes. (This could be done as some sort of Ktor plugin that listens to the pipeline, but I don't want to add to much noise here).

```
suspend fun PipelineContext<Unit, ApplicationCall>.withCall(
    bodyOfCall: suspend PipelineContext<Unit, ApplicationCall>.() -> Unit
) {
    val pipeline = this
    val appCallContext = buildAppCallContext(this.call)
    withContext(appCallContext) {
        pipeline.bodyOfCall()
    }
}

internal suspend fun buildAppCallContext(call: ApplicationCall): CoroutineContext {
    var context = coroutineContext
    val callElement = ApplicationCallElement(call)
    context = context.plus(callElement)
    return context
}
```

And then we can use it all together like in this test case below where we are able to get the call from a nested suspending function:

```
suspend fun getSomethingFromCall(): String {
    val call = coroutineContext[ApplicationCallElement.Key]?.call ?: throw Exception("Element not set")
    return call.parameters["key"] ?: throw Exception("Parameter not set")
}


fun Application.myApp() {

    routing {
        route("/foo") {
            get {
                withCall {
                    call.respondText(getSomethingFromCall())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class ApplicationCallTest {

    @Test
    fun `we can get the application call in a nested function`() {
        withTestApplication({ myApp() }) {
            with(handleRequest(HttpMethod.Get, "/foo?key=bar")) {
                assertEquals(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.status())
                assertEquals("bar", response.content)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Ah, dam - I see my answer is pretty similar to @amanin. Ah well, going to leave it here as maybe the helper functions add some implementation ideas.